# PublishTrimmed with Autofac assembly scanning

Tags: c#, autofac

I have `<PublishTrimmed>` enabled for my C# .NET 6 console app. It uses Autofac to register types. In some cases, I scan the current application for classes implementing an interface like so:

```cs
// Register all types deriving from CliFx's ICommand. These are all of our supported subcommands.
builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly())
    .Where(t => t.IsAssignableTo(typeof(ICommand)));
```

I get an analysis warning here because `RegisterAssemblyTypes()` is decorated with the `RequiresUnreferencedCode` attribute. However, all of my `ICommand` implementations are still available at run time (determined by running all of the subcommands and seeing the program function).

I have chosen to suppress this analysis issue using the `UnconditionalSuppressMessage` attribute on the calling method, but I'd like to understand if I'm doing the right thing. I did read several topics in the MS docs about trimming, but it is still not clear to me how these `ICommand` subclasses are not getting stripped. Can someone explain to me how I can tell if certain assembly scanning operations for DI purposes are safe for trimming or not? Is it because I'm scanning the "executing assembly" that it is safe?

Answer (score 0):

Using this registration pattern means that some functionality may be broken in your trimmed application, as the trimmer can't know at publish time what type is being passed to `IsAssignableTo`.

I'd recommend reading this section of the [dotnet documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/trimming/fixing-warnings#reacting-to-trim-warnings) on the warnings in general.

[This particular section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/trimming/fixing-warnings#functionality-with-requirements-on-its-input) on inputs would be more specifically relevant to you I think.